# Hot reload flutter application on web on every save VSCode

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I wanted to know how to use vscode to automatically hot reload flutter application on web on every save VSCode. Debugger attaches to the android emulator by default and hot reloads on every save. But I want that to happen with chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

As per Flutter FAQ, `Web Hot Reload` is not yet supported. Please refer to this [Flutter Web FAQ](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web)